# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined--- in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

imageupload.ts

```
onChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    Storage.put(this.image, file, {
        contentType: 'image/jpg'
    })
    .then (result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

imageupload.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" accept='image/jpg' (change)="onChange($e)"/>
  </div>
```

I am trying to upload an image to s3 in angular using was amplify. I followed the react code and tried to write in ts and HTML file. But after choosing the image the following error is visible.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$e` is not defined.
You want to pass in the event, which is defined as [`$event` in angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event).

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" accept='image/jpg' (change)="onChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

This should do the trick.